# Map XML tags with dot(.) to C# object

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML file which have some tags with dot(.), now i am using "StringWriter"
to Map XML data with C#, but i am not able to handle XML tags which have dot(.) in tag name like:- "Customer.Name", how can i map this with C# class.
I had give XmlElement with my class model, but still i am not getting values map with my class.

Can any one give me suggestion.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "PARENTNAME")]   
public string PARENTNAME { get; set; }  //This is perfect mapped
[XmlElement(ElementName = "DISPLAYCONTACT.CONTACTNAME")]
public string DISPLAYCONTACTCONTACTNAME { get; set; } // This is not mapped
[XmlElement(ElementName = "DISPLAYCONTACT.COMPANYNAME")]
public string DISPLAYCONTACTCOMPANYNAME { get; set; }
```

Convert XML to C#

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(custome‌​rString);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
doc.WriteTo(xw);
String XmlString = sw.ToString();
string xmlToJson = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
var deserialized = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
var custome‌​r = new CusGetResIn();
custome‌​r= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CusGetResIn>(deserialized);
```

Also Tried:-

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CusGetResIn));
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XmlString));
CusGetResIn resultingMessage = (CusGetResIn)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
```

XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <control>
        <status>success</status>
        <senderid>Intacct_ISB</senderid>
        <controlid>17/12/2018</controlid>
        <uniqueid>false</uniqueid>
        <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>
    </control>
    <operation>
        <authentication>
            <status>success</status>
            <userid>vinit1</userid>
            <companyid>FASTMORE-trial</companyid>
            <locationid></locationid>
            <sessiontimestamp>2018-12-19T00:41:15-08:00</sessiontimestamp>
        </authentication>
        <result>
            <status>success</status>
            <function>readByQuery</function>
            <controlid>testFunctionId</controlid>
            <data listtype="customer" count="31" totalcount="31" numremaining="0" resultId="">
                <customer>
                    <RECORDNO>5</RECORDNO>
                    <CUSTOMERID>CUST-00101</CUSTOMERID>
                    <NAME>Sun Microsystems - EBC</NAME>
                    <ENTITY>CCUST-00101</ENTITY>
                    <PARENTKEY></PARENTKEY>
                    <PARENTID></PARENTID>
                    <PARENTNAME></PARENTNAME>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.CONTACTNAME>Sun Microsystems - EBC(CCUST-00101)</DISPLAYCONTACT.CONTACTNAME>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.COMPANYNAME>Sun Microsystems - EBC</DISPLAYCONTACT.COMPANYNAME>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.PREFIX></DISPLAYCONTACT.PREFIX>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.FIRSTNAME></DISPLAYCONTACT.FIRSTNAME>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.LASTNAME></DISPLAYCONTACT.LASTNAME>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.INITIAL></DISPLAYCONTACT.INITIAL>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.PRINTAS>Sun Microsystems - Executive Briefing Center</DISPLAYCONTACT.PRINTAS>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.TAXABLE>true</DISPLAYCONTACT.TAXABLE>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.TAXGROUP></DISPLAYCONTACT.TAXGROUP>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.PHONE1></DISPLAYCONTACT.PHONE1>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.PHONE2></DISPLAYCONTACT.PHONE2>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.CELLPHONE></DISPLAYCONTACT.CELLPHONE>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.PAGER></DISPLAYCONTACT.PAGER>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.FAX></DISPLAYCONTACT.FAX>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.EMAIL1>sevans@intacct.com</DISPLAYCONTACT.EMAIL1>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.EMAIL2></DISPLAYCONTACT.EMAIL2>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.URL1></DISPLAYCONTACT.URL1>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.URL2></DISPLAYCONTACT.URL2>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.VISIBLE>true</DISPLAYCONTACT.VISIBLE>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS1>1245 Williams Lane</DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS1>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS2></DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS2>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.CITY>San Jose</DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.CITY>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.STATE>CA</DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.STATE>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.ZIP>95112</DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.ZIP>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRY>USA</DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRY>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRYCODE></DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRYCODE>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LATITUDE></DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LATITUDE>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LONGITUDE></DISPLAYCONTACT.MAILADDRESS.LONGITUDE>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACT.STATUS>active</DISPLAYCONTACT.STATUS>
                    <TERMNAME>2/10 Net30</TERMNAME>
                    <TERMVALUE>2:10:1#30#1%:W:</TERMVALUE>
                    <CUSTREPID>EMP-002</CUSTREPID>
                    <CUSTREPNAME>Joanna Drake</CUSTREPNAME>
                    <RESALENO></RESALENO>
                    <TAXID></TAXID>
                    <CREDITLIMIT></CREDITLIMIT>
                    <TOTALDUE>3525172.72</TOTALDUE>
                    <COMMENTS></COMMENTS>
                    <ACCOUNTLABEL></ACCOUNTLABEL>
                    <ARACCOUNT>4000</ARACCOUNT>
                    <ARACCOUNTTITLE>Sales</ARACCOUNTTITLE>
                    <LAST_INVOICEDATE>10/01/2012</LAST_INVOICEDATE>
                    <LAST_STATEMENTDATE></LAST_STATEMENTDATE>
                    <DELIVERY_OPTIONS>Print#~#E-Mail</DELIVERY_OPTIONS>
                    <TERRITORYID></TERRITORYID>
                    <SHIPPINGMETHOD>Delivery</SHIPPINGMETHOD>
                    <CUSTTYPE>Corporate</CUSTTYPE>
                    <GLGRPKEY></GLGRPKEY>
                    <GLGROUP></GLGROUP>
                    <PRICESCHEDULE></PRICESCHEDULE>
                    <DISCOUNT></DISCOUNT>
                    <PRICELIST></PRICELIST>
                    <VSOEPRICELIST></VSOEPRICELIST>
                    <CURRENCY></CURRENCY>
                    <CONTACTINFO.CONTACTNAME></CONTACTINFO.CONTACTNAME>
                    <CONTACTINFO.PREFIX></CONTACTINFO.PREFIX>
                    <CONTACTINFO.FIRSTNAME></CONTACTINFO.FIRSTNAME>
                    <CONTACTINFO.INITIAL></CONTACTINFO.INITIAL>
                    <CONTACTINFO.LASTNAME></CONTACTINFO.LASTNAME>
                    <CONTACTINFO.COMPANYNAME></CONTACTINFO.COMPANYNAME>
                    <CONTACTINFO.PRINTAS></CONTACTINFO.PRINTAS>
                    <CONTACTINFO.PHONE1></CONTACTINFO.PHONE1>
                    <CONTACTINFO.PHONE2></CONTACTINFO.PHONE2>
                    <CONTACTINFO.CELLPHONE></CONTACTINFO.CELLPHONE>
                    <CONTACTINFO.PAGER></CONTACTINFO.PAGER>
                    <CONTACTINFO.FAX></CONTACTINFO.FAX>
                    <CONTACTINFO.EMAIL1></CONTACTINFO.EMAIL1>
                    <CONTACTINFO.EMAIL2></CONTACTINFO.EMAIL2>
                    <CONTACTINFO.URL1></CONTACTINFO.URL1>
                    <CONTACTINFO.URL2></CONTACTINFO.URL2>
                    <CONTACTINFO.VISIBLE></CONTACTINFO.VISIBLE>
                    <CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS1></CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS1>
                    <CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS2></CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS2>
                    <CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.CITY></CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.CITY>
                    <CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.STATE></CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.STATE>
                    <CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.ZIP></CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.ZIP>
                    <CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRY></CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRY>
                    <CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRYCODE></CONTACTINFO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRYCODE>
                    <SHIPTO.CONTACTNAME></SHIPTO.CONTACTNAME>
                    <SHIPTO.PREFIX></SHIPTO.PREFIX>
                    <SHIPTO.FIRSTNAME></SHIPTO.FIRSTNAME>
                    <SHIPTO.INITIAL></SHIPTO.INITIAL>
                    <SHIPTO.LASTNAME></SHIPTO.LASTNAME>
                    <SHIPTO.COMPANYNAME></SHIPTO.COMPANYNAME>
                    <SHIPTO.PRINTAS></SHIPTO.PRINTAS>
                    <SHIPTO.TAXABLE></SHIPTO.TAXABLE>
                    <SHIPTO.TAXGROUP></SHIPTO.TAXGROUP>
                    <SHIPTO.PHONE1></SHIPTO.PHONE1>
                    <SHIPTO.PHONE2></SHIPTO.PHONE2>
                    <SHIPTO.CELLPHONE></SHIPTO.CELLPHONE>
                    <SHIPTO.PAGER></SHIPTO.PAGER>
                    <SHIPTO.FAX></SHIPTO.FAX>
                    <SHIPTO.EMAIL1></SHIPTO.EMAIL1>
                    <SHIPTO.EMAIL2></SHIPTO.EMAIL2>
                    <SHIPTO.URL1></SHIPTO.URL1>
                    <SHIPTO.URL2></SHIPTO.URL2>
                    <SHIPTO.VISIBLE></SHIPTO.VISIBLE>
                    <SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS1></SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS1>
                    <SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS2></SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS2>
                    <SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.CITY></SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.CITY>
                    <SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.STATE></SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.STATE>
                    <SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.ZIP></SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.ZIP>
                    <SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRY></SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRY>
                    <SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRYCODE></SHIPTO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRYCODE>
                    <BILLTO.CONTACTNAME></BILLTO.CONTACTNAME>
                    <BILLTO.PREFIX></BILLTO.PREFIX>
                    <BILLTO.FIRSTNAME></BILLTO.FIRSTNAME>
                    <BILLTO.INITIAL></BILLTO.INITIAL>
                    <BILLTO.LASTNAME></BILLTO.LASTNAME>
                    <BILLTO.COMPANYNAME></BILLTO.COMPANYNAME>
                    <BILLTO.PRINTAS></BILLTO.PRINTAS>
                    <BILLTO.TAXABLE></BILLTO.TAXABLE>
                    <BILLTO.TAXGROUP></BILLTO.TAXGROUP>
                    <BILLTO.PHONE1></BILLTO.PHONE1>
                    <BILLTO.PHONE2></BILLTO.PHONE2>
                    <BILLTO.CELLPHONE></BILLTO.CELLPHONE>
                    <BILLTO.PAGER></BILLTO.PAGER>
                    <BILLTO.FAX></BILLTO.FAX>
                    <BILLTO.EMAIL1></BILLTO.EMAIL1>
                    <BILLTO.EMAIL2></BILLTO.EMAIL2>
                    <BILLTO.URL1></BILLTO.URL1>
                    <BILLTO.URL2></BILLTO.URL2>
                    <BILLTO.VISIBLE></BILLTO.VISIBLE>
                    <BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS1></BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS1>
                    <BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS2></BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.ADDRESS2>
                    <BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.CITY></BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.CITY>
                    <BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.STATE></BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.STATE>
                    <BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.ZIP></BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.ZIP>
                    <BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRY></BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRY>
                    <BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRYCODE></BILLTO.MAILADDRESS.COUNTRYCODE>
                    <STATUS>active</STATUS>
                    <ONETIME>false</ONETIME>
                    <CUSTMESSAGEID></CUSTMESSAGEID>
                    <ONHOLD>false</ONHOLD>
                    <PRCLST_OVERRIDE>C</PRCLST_OVERRIDE>
                    <OEPRCLSTKEY></OEPRCLSTKEY>
                    <OEPRICESCHEDKEY></OEPRICESCHEDKEY>
                    <ENABLEONLINECARDPAYMENT>true</ENABLEONLINECARDPAYMENT>
                    <ENABLEONLINEACHPAYMENT>true</ENABLEONLINEACHPAYMENT>
                    <VSOEPRCLSTKEY></VSOEPRCLSTKEY>
                    <WHENMODIFIED>12/18/2018 16:07:40</WHENMODIFIED>
                    <ARINVOICEPRINTTEMPLATEID></ARINVOICEPRINTTEMPLATEID>
                    <OEQUOTEPRINTTEMPLATEID></OEQUOTEPRINTTEMPLATEID>
                    <OEORDERPRINTTEMPLATEID></OEORDERPRINTTEMPLATEID>
                    <OELISTPRINTTEMPLATEID></OELISTPRINTTEMPLATEID>
                    <OEINVOICEPRINTTEMPLATEID></OEINVOICEPRINTTEMPLATEID>
                    <OEADJPRINTTEMPLATEID></OEADJPRINTTEMPLATEID>
                    <OEOTHERPRINTTEMPLATEID></OEOTHERPRINTTEMPLATEID>
                    <WHENCREATED>01/01/1970 00:00:00</WHENCREATED>
                    <CREATEDBY></CREATEDBY>
                    <MODIFIEDBY>1</MODIFIEDBY>
                    <OBJECTRESTRICTION>Unrestricted</OBJECTRESTRICTION>
                    <DISPLAYCONTACTKEY>38</DISPLAYCONTACTKEY>
                    <CONTACTKEY></CONTACTKEY>
                    <SHIPTOKEY></SHIPTOKEY>
                    <BILLTOKEY></BILLTOKEY>
                    <CUSTREPKEY>2</CUSTREPKEY>
                    <SHIPVIAKEY>1</SHIPVIAKEY>
                    <TERRITORYKEY></TERRITORYKEY>
                    <TERMSKEY>1</TERMSKEY>
                    <ACCOUNTLABELKEY></ACCOUNTLABELKEY>
                    <ACCOUNTKEY>25</ACCOUNTKEY>
                    <CUSTTYPEKEY>1</CUSTTYPEKEY>
                    <PRICESCHEDULEKEY></PRICESCHEDULEKEY>
                    <OFFSETGLACCOUNTNO></OFFSETGLACCOUNTNO>
                    <OFFSETGLACCOUNTNOTITLE></OFFSETGLACCOUNTNOTITLE>
                    <ADVBILLBY></ADVBILLBY>
                    <ADVBILLBYTYPE></ADVBILLBYTYPE>
                    <SUPDOCID></SUPDOCID>
                    <MEGAENTITYKEY></MEGAENTITYKEY>
                    <MEGAENTITYID></MEGAENTITYID>
                    <MEGAENTITYNAME></MEGAENTITYNAME>
                    <RESTRICTEDLOCATIONS></RESTRICTEDLOCATIONS>
                    <RESTRICTEDDEPARTMENTS></RESTRICTEDDEPARTMENTS>
                </customer></data>
        </result>
    </operation>
</response>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the `XmlSerializer` class to do this?

Comment: no there is no reason, i am also trying that too, but it's also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pasted your XML in an **XMLFile1.xml** and pasted it in Visual Studio to generate classes, so this will be a lot of autogenerated code... **warning**

> could not fit auto gen code...
>
> Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 93977

Full code here:
https://pastebin.com/VxzNUjsv

Smaller version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
  <RECORDNO>5</RECORDNO>
  <CUSTOMERID>CUST-00101</CUSTOMERID>
  <PARENTNAME>parent</PARENTNAME>
  <DISPLAYCONTACT.CONTACTNAME>Sun Microsystems - EBC(CCUST-00101)</DISPLAYCONTACT.CONTACTNAME>
  <DISPLAYCONTACT.COMPANYNAME>Sun Microsystems - EBC</DISPLAYCONTACT.COMPANYNAME>
</customer>
```

and C# code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var sreader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\JP\source\repos\soXmlParsing\soXmlParsing\XMLFile1.xml")))
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sreader))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(customer));
                var test = (customer)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                Console.WriteLine(test.PARENTNAME);
                Console.WriteLine(test.DISPLAYCONTACTCONTACTNAME);
            }
        }
    }


    // NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class customer
    {

        private byte rECORDNOField;

        private string cUSTOMERIDField;

        private string pARENTNAMEField;

        private string dISPLAYCONTACTCONTACTNAMEField;

        private string dISPLAYCONTACTCOMPANYNAMEField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte RECORDNO
        {
            get
            {
                return this.rECORDNOField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.rECORDNOField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string CUSTOMERID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cUSTOMERIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cUSTOMERIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string PARENTNAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pARENTNAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pARENTNAMEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DISPLAYCONTACT.CONTACTNAME")]
        public string DISPLAYCONTACTCONTACTNAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dISPLAYCONTACTCONTACTNAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dISPLAYCONTACTCONTACTNAMEField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DISPLAYCONTACT.COMPANYNAME")]
        public string DISPLAYCONTACTCOMPANYNAME
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dISPLAYCONTACTCOMPANYNAMEField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dISPLAYCONTACTCOMPANYNAMEField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for you answer i will try to generate auto code and update you

Comment: Can you tell me how can i convert xml to class in VS?

Comment: There is a special paste option. So I select the full XML and `ctrl+c` and in VS it's edit -> paste special -> paste xml as classes.

Answer (score 4):

Quick test shows `XmlSerializer` can handle this pretty easily

Test class:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Foo.Alpha")]
    public string Alpha {get;set;}

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Foo.Beta")]
    public string Beta {get;set;}
}
```

Example method:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var src = @"<Test>
    <Foo.Alpha>value 1</Foo.Alpha>
    <Foo.Beta>value 2</Foo.Beta>
    </Test>";

    using (var sreader = new StringReader(src))
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sreader))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
        var test = (Test)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Console.WriteLine(test.Alpha);
        Console.WriteLine(test.Beta);
    }
}
```

---

Update: since the XML document you are processing is very large, you should consider what you actually need to do. If you need to manipulate the entire document as objects then the approach taken in JP Hellemons's answer may be the way to go. If you are only interested in certain fields, then it may be better to load the XML into an `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` and extract the fields you are interested in from that, or even write a forward-only parser using `XmlReader` to do the same thing.

Comment: i have tried this i AM getting <response xmlns=''> was not expected. error

Comment: Then I think you need to expand your question to show the XML you are trying to parse and the full definition of the target class you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: Hello, Please check question i had added my XML

Comment: Totally agree on @mistertribs answer update. Use a section of the large document is recommended. Use Linq or Xpath to navigate and populate a custom poco object.